# Declaring new types

Tags: c#, types, numbers

Let's suppose that I have the following class:

```
class Number{

}
```

I want then to declare variables of `Number` type, and give them a value like in `int` or `uint` or any kind of variables:

```
Number n = 14;
```

I am not sure if my question is good, but please help me, because I am new in C#

Comment: Almost exactly what you want - [How to: Implement User-Defined Conversions Between Structs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zk2z37d3.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

You can create implicit conversion operators to handle cases like this.  Your class needs a constructor that the implicit conversion operator will call.  For example:

```
class Number
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public Number(int initialValue)
    {
        Value = initialValue;
    }

    public static implicit operator Number(int initialValue)
    {
        return new Number(initialValue);
    }
}
```

Then the line

```
Number n = 14;
```

Will be effectively equivalent to

```
Number n = new Number(14);
```

You can add an operator to the class to go in the other direction too:

```
public static implicit operator int(Number number)
{
    if (number == null) {
        // Or do something else (return 0, -1, whatever makes sense in the
        // context of your application).
        throw new ArgumentNullException("number");
    }

    return number.Value;
}
```

**Be careful** with implicit operators.  They are nice syntactic sugar, but they can also make it harder to tell what's really going on in a particular chunk of code.  You can also use explicit operators, which require a type-cast to invoke.

Comment: And it is still a small class, but it will become a huge class. My plans are to make a type of number of infinite precision with more operations thant `double`.

Comment: Ok.  If it represents a value, you should use a struct instead of a class.  If you use a class, `Number m = n;` means that `m` and `n` point to the same `Number` object -- probably not what you want.  If you use a struct, `Number m = n;` will copy the value of `n` onto a new instance, `m`.  This is in line with other primitive value types.  (Using a struct also means that variables typed `Number` cannot be null.)

Comment: You should also make it immutable, especially if you make it a struct.  Actually, on second though, if your `Number` has infinite precision then it can't have a finite size, unless it just contains a reference to another data structure, so it probably should be a class, not a struct.

Comment: @Servy: A good reason why C# should support overloading the assignment operator, at least for structs.

Comment: @cdhowie Even if you could overload the assignment operator you still wouldn't want to make this object a struct, given that it represents an indeterminate, and possibly large, amount of data.

Comment: @Servy Sure you would.  This is commonplace in C++ all the time; the assignment/copy operator would be responsible for transferring state, which might mean doing a deep copy.  There's no other way to obtain value semantics on a type whose size is not constant.  (If the data is really big, a copy-on-write flag can be used to quickly make copies while preserving value-type semantics.)  However, if we are talking about an immutable struct anyway, then an immutable class with modifiers that return new instances would be sufficient.

Comment: @cdhowie You can't allocate stack space for an item with an indeterminate size.  For that reason it's not just undesirable, it's actually *impossible* for a value type to actually have an indeterminate size.  If it represents a value of indeterminate size then the only way to make it a struct is for that struct to have a pointer/reference to a class that has space allocated on the heap.  If you're going to have the underlying data in a class on the heap anyway there isn't usually much value in exposing it via a value type.

Comment: @Servy Perhaps. On the other hand, value types better represent value semantics.  Even if you have a reference under the hood, overloading the assignment operator would allow one to present the illusion of a value type (the reference being an implementation detail).

Comment: @cdhowie You would simply want to ensure that the class is immutable.  `string` is the *perfect* example of this.  It logically does represent a single value, but it also represents a large and indeterminate amount of data.  It was chosen to be represented as an immutable reference type.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at [implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) to create an implicit conversion from int to your number class.

Answer (score 1):

You can overload operators in your class:

```
class Number
{
    public static Number operator=(int i)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

BTW, for simple and small classes like this, it's better to use structs, not classes.

Comment: You cannot overload the assignment operator in C#.

Comment: I initially thought the same thing, but you can't override `=`. You have to use implicit conversions instead. See the list of [overloadable operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/8edha89s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)